# eliminate duplicates in Android drawable folders

Tags: android, android-layout, duplicates, drawable

I want to have two different layouts (in layout and layout-land), one that is landscape and one that is portrait.  Both these layouts will use some of the same images, eg,. drawable-hdpi and drawable-land-hdpi currently have copies of the same image 'horn.png' and same is for drawable-xhdpi and drawable-land-xhdpi, etc... Is there a way to not duplicate the images everywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you will not put duplicates in `drawable-land` folders, the system will take the images from the other folder even in landscape mode.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know if Android would do this implicitly or not and the documentation just sort of hinted at it, thanks.